# Text Decoration Not Affecting Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section on my website which has a link but it has an underline so I tried `text-decoration: none;` but to no avail. Can someone please help me with the problem?

Code:

```
<div class="content2">
  <div class="twitterfeed">
    <h3>Twitter Feed</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="recent">
    <h3 class="text3">Recent News<span class="slash">   /   </span><span class="text4">Get updates from us!</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="readnews">
    <a href="themes.goodlayers2.com/musicclub/blog-full-with-right-sidebar/"> <p class="readall"> Read All News </p></a>
  </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">

.content2 {
  background: #191919;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.twitterfeed {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 140px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Didot, Georgia, sans-serif;
}

.recent {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 230px;
}

.readnews {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 457px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.text3 {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Goudy Old Style", Optima, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text4 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #6CB9D9;
}

.readall {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="themes.goodlayers2.com/musicclub/blog-full-with-right-sidebar/" class="readall"> <p> Read All News </p></a>
```

You can keep the p element.

Answer (score 1):

You have a DIV element wich contains an A wich contains a P.
The DIV has a class with the text decoration, but you need to apply it to the A elements, so you could use`.readnews a{ text-deciration:none; }`
On the other hand, in HTML you shouldn't add a BLOCK element (P tag) inside an INLINE element (A tag), so that's technically wrong. Anyway, it will work, but you're applying the text-decoration:none to a P, while you should add it to the A... The A tag will always be more "important" than any other element (talking about CSS).

If you want to keep your HTML elements you should add the A inside the P, so:
DIV > P > A
And then add the styles to the A tag.

Answer (score 0):

Give the surrounding anchor tag the class *readall* instead of the paragraph. I'd get rid of that p-element here anyway.